# Reversing ONLY integers in list without slice or reverse()

Tags: python, list, int, slice, reverse

I am trying to create a program to reverse only the integers in a given list, ignoring floats and strings. In addition, It cannot use any built in functions to do so (reverse() and [::-1]). So far, I have

```
def intvert(lst):
    finallst = []
    for i in range(len(lst)-1,-1,-1):
        if i == type(int):
            finallst.append(i)
        elif i != type(int):
            continue
    return finallst
```

However, this only produces [] as the output

example: (1,g,2.6,2,3,4,h,dfgs,dsgfgdsg,5) becomes (5,4,3,2,1)

Comment: `i == type(int)`: that will never happen. You want: `type(lst[i]) == int` or better: `isinstance(lst[i], int)`.

Comment: You are comparing value with type of type? Really?

Comment: Quick question - Why?

Comment: What do you mean by reversing the integers?Can you provide an example?

Comment: As in, it will only look for the integers in the list and reverse them (5,g,6,t,4) becomes (4,6,5)

Comment: Please update your question with more examples like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason nothing's getting appended to your list is because your *if* condition is erroneous. By typing `if i == type(int)` you're trying to verify if your counter variable "i" (always an integer) is equal to the type of Python's reserved keyword "int"... which doesn't really make sense.

Here's an if condition that should get this working:

```python
if isinstance(lst[i],int):
    finallst.append(lst[i])
```

You need to index into a value in your list ([some indexing exercises here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html)). The "isinstance()" method checks the type of the value at the ith position in "lst" to type *int*. If True, the value is appended to your list.

Fyi: You also don't need the *elif* or an *else* block in this case.

Comment: Note that jp_data_analysis's solution below using Generators is a fantastic and elegant solution. However, I recommend getting comfortable with basic array/list indexing first before moving onto Python Generators.

Answer (score 3):

A generator is useful for these kinds of tasks. Note it is better to use `isinstance` versus `type`. Also you do not have to explicitly check for non-int types if you aren't going to do anything with them.

```
def intvert(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)-1, -1, -1):
        if isinstance(lst[i], int):
            yield lst[i]

list(intvert([1, 2, 3, 4]))

# [4, 3, 2, 1]

list(intvert([1, 'test', 2, ['another test'], 3, 4]))

# [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Note that the generator function can be optimised further by converting it into a generator *expression*:

```
def intvert(lst):
    return (lst[i] for i in range(len(lst)-1, -1, -1) if isinstance(lst[i], int))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_int(val):
    if type(val) == int:
        return True
    else:
         return False



lis=[1,"aa",2,"b",3,"c"]
lim=[]
for x in lis:
    if is_int(x)==True:
        lim.append(x)

k=len(lim)

for i in range(k//2):
    a=lim[i]
    lim[i]=lim[k-1]
    lim[k-1]=a

print(lim)


'''this code does so same logic as yours tell me if you didnt understand.i used 
type operater you can use something else.'''
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter your list you can use list comprehensions:

```
input_list = [1,2.6,'hi',3,'blah',{},99]

filtered_list = [x for x in input_list if type(x) is int]

>>> [1,3,99]
```

Then you can reverse that list in whatever way you want according to your homework constraints.  Normally you'd call .reverse() on the filtered_list but up to you.  If list.reverse() is out, I don't know if list.instert() is allowed, but if it is, then you can do:

```
reversed_filtered_list = []
for i in filtered_list:
    reversed_filtered_list.insert(0, i)
```